# Converting char to ascii decimal value

Tags: c, arrays, char, ascii

How can I convert char array into its ascii decimal value.

This array:

```
uint8_t character[4];
character[0] = '1';
character[1] = '2';
character[2] = '3';
character[3] = '4';
```

To:

```
uint32_t value = 49505152
```

Thanks! and if possible convert it back again.

Comment: Conversion back in that format is probably impossible. There is no way to know if "49505152" is equal to '4', '9', 50', '5', '1', '52' or any of the other permutations.

Comment: Possibly `int value = (int)character[0];`

Comment: `uint8_t c[4] = "1234"; uint32_t value = 100*(100*(100*c[0] + c[1]) + c[2]) + c[3];`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, giving complete solutions doesn't help students learning.

Comment: I guess that is probably to use hexadecimal.

Comment: or value = 0x31323334

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i will be using this formula uint32_t value = 100*(100*(100*c[0] + c[1]) + c[2]) + c[3]; to write it on my mcu flash. I think instead of converting it back again I'll just convert the other values to uint32_t for comparison purpose. Thank you. This helps a lot. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I convert char array into its ascii decimal value.

`'1'` is `49`. So `'1' * 100 + '2'` is `4950`. I suggest a for loop.

> Thanks! and if possible convert it back again.

`49505152 % 100` is `52`, `49505152 / 100` is `495051`

Again, a for loop would be useful.

With this infos, I guess you will complete your homework in no time.

Comment: That only works for ASCII values up to 99. So much for most of the lower case letters...

Comment: It's okey. I'll be using '0'-'9' only. The purpose of this is to write 4digit pin code on my MCU flash memory. @BodoThiesen Thank you so much. I need to convert it back again so I can display its value on my serial monitor. :)